# How does Google treat underscores in site map URLs?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, sitemap

Google is currently reporting that my URLs are invalid within my sitemap. Here's an example of a document that was considered erroneous by Google's validator:

[image: XML Sitemap]

For each of the URLs in the map, Google reported

> **URL not allowed** | **This url is not allowed for a Sitemap at this location.**

With a little searching, I read that Google combines underscore-separated strings inside of URLs, which would mean that `https://www.example.com/foo_bar_baz` would be read by the bot as `https://www.example.com/foobarbaz`, which may not actually be an existing page (which would render an HTTP 404). Am I wrong? If not, is there any way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: The underscore-separated string combination does not have sense. Google recommends using hyphens instead of underscores, but I don't think underscores being the problem here. Do you have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in the first line?

Comment: @marcanuy So, that (the xml declaration in the header, along with the encoding) is being generated.

Answer (score 3):

The error, *This url is not allowed for a Sitemap at this location.* is actually rather self explanatory. It has nothing to do with underscores (_) which are perfectly valid.

Simply put, you cannot refer to another domain name within your sitemap. A sitemap **must** refer to the domain name on which it resides. The purpose for a sitemap is to inform a crawler of **your** site's URLs. In your example, it appears you are referring to BuzzFeed.com.

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps

> The Sitemaps protocol allows a webmaster to inform search engines
>   about URLs on **a** website that are available for crawling. A Sitemap
>   is an XML file that **lists the URLs for a site**. It allows
>   webmasters to include additional information about each URL: when it
>   was last updated, how often it changes, and how important it is in
>   relation to other URLs in the site. This allows search engines to
>   crawl the site more intelligently. Sitemaps are a URL inclusion
>   protocol and complement robots.txt, a URL exclusion protocol.

From: https://www.sitemaps.org/index.html

> Sitemaps are an easy way for webmasters to **inform search engines
>   about pages on their sites** that are available for crawling. In its
>   simplest form, a Sitemap is an XML file that **lists URLs for a site**
>   along with additional metadata about each URL (when it was last
>   updated, how often it usually changes, and how important it is,
>   relative to other URLs in the site) so that search engines can more
>   intelligently crawl the site.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702004/why-wont-google-accept-my-sitemap-xml-url-not-allowed-this-url-is-not-allowed

> That error usually means that you have an URL pointing to a different
>   Domain from yours.

Another typical reason for the error is when a relative URL is offered instead of an absolute URL. The URL **must** include the protocol HTTP or HTTPS, the domain name of your site, and the URI for the page. The URL must be fully valid including a trailing slash where the web server does not provide one. It is likely better to always provide a trailing slash.

With sitemaps.org, Google, Wikipedia, there seems to be no reference to the requirement that the URL location refer to the site on which the sitemap resides. However, the purpose of the sitemap makes it clear that the sitemap is to aide a crawler to access pages within the site for which the sitemap is created for and that the sitemap for the domain must reside on the domain preferably/traditionally within the root though not required.